# Inverse Matrix3f

Tags: android, matrix-inverse

In the `android.renderscript` package there is a `Matrix3f` and `Matrix4f` class.

The `Matrix4f` class has an `inverse()` method, but the `Matrix3f` does not.

To calculate the inverse of a `Matrix3f` instance, is there perhaps a utility class or maybe a smart workaround to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to write your own inverse function, which is not that hard to do, you might use the following trick.

Say you have a 3x3 matrix A

```
A = [[1 2 3]
     [4 5 6]
     [7 8 9]]
```

You can construct 4x4 matrix B

```
B = [[1 2 3 0]
     [4 5 6 0]
     [7 8 9 0]
     [0 0 0 1]]
```

and take the inverse of B. Call the inverses A_inv and B_inv. Then,

```
B_inv = [[      0]
         [A_inv 0]
         [      0]
         [0 0 0 1]]
```